# how to write build script command for Node Js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, build

my friends, I am a beginner and I am trying to build my project that was built with Node, but I don't know the build script. I searched for it a lot but I didn't find a solution. Thank you

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "engines":{
    "node":"16.x"
  } ,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a file called `server.js` in the root of your project? If so, just run `yarn start` (since the package.json includes: `"start": "node server.js"`). Don't forget to install dependencies first, with `yarn`. Be sure to run these commands from the root of your project (where the package.json is)

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more detail to get a proper answer. I suggest including more of your code, and explaining the actual and expected output, and describe what you've tried yourself so far.

Comment: yes, there is a file called server.js, the main file in my project when I try to deploy my project on vercel I get this error "Error: Your `package.json` file is missing a `build` property inside the `scripts` property."

Answer (score 1):

I would say the error you are getting is the same as described in [Missing Build Scripts (Errors - Vercel Docs)](https://vercel.com/docs/errors#error-list/missing-build-script).

Apparently, you get this error message when you have a `package.json` file located in the root directory of your project, but you have no `api` directory and no `vercel.json` configuration.

They recommend to set your `package.json` file to something similar to this:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "[my-framework] build --output public"
  }
}
```

However, for now it is not possible to have a server-run Node.js web app hosted directly with Vercel.

> [Vercel](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/tree/main/examples#what-is-vercel) is a cloud platform for **static frontends** and serverless functions.

In order to deploy a Node.js API with Vercel you would need to use their [serverless functions](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions/supported-languages#node.js) or use the [Node.js helpers](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/node-js/node-js-request-and-response-objects).

Comment: [my-framework] mean node or express

Comment: another  Error: The `build` property in vercel.json needs to be an object

Comment: `[my-framework]` actually means any bundler, module compiler, build tool or frontend framework CLI that gives an option for creating a static build of your project to serve with Vercel (e.g.: create-react-app, create-vue, ng, webpack, vite, etc.)

Comment: The `build` property in `vercel.json` needs to be an object, unlike in `package.json`. Its content should be set according to the configuration mentioned in [Project config with vercel.json](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and the workaround was to create a `vercel.json` file in the root directory with the following config:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "server.js",
            "use": "@now/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "server.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

This avoids the use of the `/api` folder for simple projects and tells vercel to serve this API as a serverless function.
Reference: https://dev.to/tirthpatel/node-js-express-app-on-vercel-develop-run-deploy-524a
Original Vercel guide: https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel